# Java capture sound real-time

Tags: java, audio, capture

I capture song in real-time with **TargetDataLine**:

```
line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

But this buffer have to be byte array. I need capture to buffer which is long array or float array. I try to convert from byte to long or float but these data are not correct.

How Can I capture with another type or covert byte to float/long in correct way?

Comment: Show us your attempt of converting.

Comment: Also, what size is your buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
float[] fBuffer = new float[buffer.length >> 2];

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
fb.get(fBuffer, 0, fBuffer.length);
```

This does the conversion for you.